# Get internal and external IP addresses in Unity 2018.2.0?

Tags: unity, c#, networking

Unity 2018.2.0 makes the [Network class obsolete](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NetworkPlayer-ipAddress.html).  I have used "Network.player.ipAddress" in my code to get the local LAN IP address.

```
    internalIP = Network.player.ipAddress;
    externalIP = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
```

What code should replace this?  What would be best practice for getting internal and external IP addresses for manual LAN and internet direct connections between server and client?

Internal/external IP addresses are needed so players can load the game, then tell their friends what their IP is to direct connect.

Comment: When you tell us why exactly you need the internal and external IP address, then we might suggest you a better solution for your problem.

Comment: @Philipp So players can load the game and tell their friends what their IP is for direct connecting.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a matchmaking server? It would be a very lightweight task, so a small and cheap cloud VM would do.

Comment: @Philipp That might be a good idea in future, but I really need an answer to this specific implementation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output the IP for every interface on the machine.

```
foreach(NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
   if(ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 || ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
   {
       foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
       {
           if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
           {
               //do what you want with the IP here... add it to a list, just get the first and break out. Whatever.
               Debug.Log(ip.Address.ToString());
           }
       }
   }  
}
```

You'll need to have access to `System.Net.NetworkInformation` in your project.

Comment: Thanks!  This works to bring up a list of IP addresses.  The problem is the first one it returns is 192.168.0.10.  That is pulled on both editor and standalone client.  Previously using Network.player.ipAddress, whenever I'd load a standalone and the editor, and try and direct connect them, they'd have a different 192.168.xxx.  So I'm wondering, is there something I can do manually to fix this, or is it something coded deeper into Unity which is now removed and I can't replicate?